# Patching Delaunay Triangles

Tags: matlab, triangulation, surface, delaunay

I have a number of 2D points x and y, and I need to color delaunay triangles, which have edges that exceed a certain limit. However I can't figure out how to write it down so that it would compare each edge of each triangle and add it to a vector of triangles that need to be patched. The end result is supposed to be a 3D surface, where color depends on the Z coordinate, except for the triangles that have been patched white. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You can try a contour plot. With your triangles and z values find the average of each triangle.